# Change only one character of all img src of a class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to change the src of **all the images which are in the 'car-image' class.**

But I do not have to change whole url. I just want to **change one character**.

I want edit this -

```
<div class="car-image">
    <img src="/cars/3_large_1.png">
</div>
```

To this-

```
<div class="car-image">
    <img src="/cars/3_large_2.png">
</div>
```

And this format is common in all the image in this class.
I tried something like this-

```
var allsrc = document.getElementsByClassName('car-image');
allsrc[0].src="/cars/3_large_2.png";
```

This is not working.
How can i do this in javascript?

Comment: To clarify, you want every image in `.car-image` to have the same source? Or are you wanting to iterate and increase that last number in the source throughout the class?

Comment: Please review my answer, i've updated it as your needs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant solution would be to use replace function with regex. If you know the image src pattern and similar changes apply to all image src, you can build a regex. In that case, instead of changing each image src one by one, you can iterate over the elements that contains `car-image` class and find out the first childNode and change the src attr.

```
// find all elements that contains class car-image
var carImgDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('car-image');

// iterate over carImgDivs and execute an imediate function to just pass the
// childNode1 that is the image. Use replace function with regex to find out the
// changed image src value and set the changed src value to childNode1
for(var i = 0; i < carImgDivs.length; i++) (function(childNode1) {
  if(childNode1) { 
    var replacedSrc = childNode1.getAttribute('src').replace(/(_)(\d)/, "$12");
    childNode1.setAttribute("src", replacedSrc);
  }
})(carImgDivs[i].childNodes[1]);
```

For a image src like `/cars/3_large_1.png`, the regular expression (_)(\d) matches a underscore that follows a digit and captures both. The `$1` in replace string `"$12"` says to keep the first capture group(underscore) as it is and `2` says to replace the second capture group(a digit) with `2`. Basically, the regex matches with `_1` in the above image src. `_` is the first capture group and `1` is the second capture group. So, in the end, the image src gets changed to `/cars/3_large_2.png`

Answer (score 3):

you are setting src of wrong node allsrc returns your div not the image.

Try this

```
allsrc[0].childNodes[1].setAttribute("src","/cars/3_large_2.png")
```

Comment: Accualy my code is like -
 
`<div class="car-image"> <img src="/cars/3_large_1.png"> </div> <div class="car-image"> <img src="/cars/5_large_1.png"> </div> <div class="car-image"> <img src="/cars/7_large_1.png"> </div> <div class="car-image"> <img src="/cars/9_large_1.png"> </div>`

I want to change all 1 in src to change to 2. using your code i have to do it manually for all images.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the src of all the images which are in the
>   'car-image' class using javascript.

You can change `<img>` `src` for all `car-image` classes like this:

```js
var all = document.getElementsByClassName('car-image');

for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++){
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName('car-image')[i].getElementsByTagName('img');
    image[0].setAttribute("src", "/cars/3_large_2.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="car-image">
  <img src="/cars/3_large_1.png">
</div>
<div class="car-image">
  <img src="/cars/5_large_1.png">
</div>
<div class="car-image">
  <img src="/cars/7_large_1.png">
</div>
<div class="car-image">
  <img src="/cars/9_large_1.png">
</div>
```

*(Inspect elements and see new src's)*

Answer (score 0):

Use(jQuery solution) :   `$( "img:nth-child(1)" ).attr('src', <new_name>);`

The `nth-child(i)` means `i`th image.

Example:

`$(".car_image img:nth-child(1)").attr('src', '/cars/3_large_2.png');`

To change all the images just remove the `:nth-child()`

Answer (score 0):

If you [include jquery in your page](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) you can do

```
$(".car-image img").attr("src", "/cars/3_large_2.png");
```

Comment: That's the same as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('car-image')[0]; 
var img = x.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
img.src = "/cars/3_large_2.png";
```